# What's the state of branches and commit right after init?

Tags: git

According to [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init), when I run `git init`, "An initial branch without any commits will be created". But when I run `git branch` to view all my local branches, the main/master branch doesn't appear. I was wondering why this is.

Also, let's say I create a branch off of main. So after the init, I do a `git checkout -b myBranch`. Where is this branch pointing to now considering there are no commits yet? Does it have an equal pointer value as main (i.e. maybe some null value) or is it actually pointing to the main branch itself? In that case, when I do create a commit from myBranch, does myBranch now point to the commit *and* still reference main in some way?

Comment: There is an unborn default branch(`master` in most cases) as told by `git status` after init. But it does not really exist yet until the first commit is created in a regular way(`git commit`). It would be hard and unfriendly if the user had to create this branch manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "branch without any commits" doesn't really exist at all. After you do `git init`, there is nothing to be found in `.git/branches`, so there's nothing for `git branch` to see, or for pretty much any other command to refer to. All `git init` has really done is set the *name* of the branch that will be created once you actually make a commit. This is stored in `.git/HEAD`, and `git commit` knows to make a new commit with no parents specifically *because* `HEAD` points to a branch that doesn't exist yet.

If you do `git checkout -b myBranch` while still in that no-commits state, git doesn't do anything except update the name of the branch in `.git/HEAD`. Now if you make a commit, you will end up with a `myBranch` branch (in `.git/refs/heads/myBranch`) pointing to it. Nothing about the previous branch name sticks around (except in the reflog, and that's temporary).

You can do this yourself at any time if you want, even if you have some history, just by editing the ref pointer in `.git/HEAD` with a text editor — change it to some branch name that doesn't exist, then make a commit. That commit will be a new root of an independent history, just as if you had done `git checkout --orphan`.